# Expected value of a path of unit line segments

Tags: probability, expectation

We start off in at the origin in a Cartesian coordinate system. We take $n$ steps (of unit length). Each step can be in any direction (any angle $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ uniformly).

Say, a random variable $C_n$ is the final coordinate after $n$ steps.

I would assume that $\mathbb{E}(C_n)=(0,0) : \forall n$. (And for $n=1$ this is easy to see.)

But I am wondering how one would calculate in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say at time $t$ you move in direction $\theta_t$, then the coordinate at time $t+1$ is $C_{t+1}=C_{t}+(\cos\theta_t,\sin\theta_t)$, so it follows $C_{n}=(\sum_n^i\cos\theta_i, \sum_n^i\sin\theta_i)$

Given $\theta_i$ is taken independently from a uniform distribution, $E(C_n)=(nE(\cos\theta), nE(\sin\theta))=(0,0)$.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. Is there any more specific way to see why the expectation is equivalent to $n(\mathbb{E}(\cos\theta), \mathbb{E}(\sin\theta))$. In particular, why you can split it up into the expectations of the coordinates separately.

Comment: @hugabor hmm actually I've assumed that $E(C_n)$ means the expectation of the two axes respectively, I'm not sure what else could it be. If you're asking why $E(\sum\cos\theta)=nE(\cos\theta)$, it is because of the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking about. I understand now. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @hugabor you're welcome :)